# backbone el for tab in tabset?

Tags: backbone.js, tabs

what html element class (or id) should be passed to a view, which displays on a tab in tabset?
some piece of code probably explain this bit more :

```
            this.articleModel = new Article.Model1();
            this.articleView = new ArticleView.View({
                model: this.articleModel
            });

            this.new_article = new Article.Model();
            this.new_article.fetch();
            this.editorView = new EditorView.EditorView({
                el : $('.tab2_area')
                ,model: this.new_article
                });

            this.tabset = new Backbone.UI.TabSet({ 
                el : $('.tab_example')
                ,alternatives : [{
                    label: 'tab1'
                    ,content: this.articleView.el
                    }
                ,{
                    label: 'tab2',
                    content: this.editorView.el
                    }       
            });
```

and coresponding html template:

```
<body>

<div id = "middle" style = "float: right; width: 80%; height: 100%;">
    <div class="tab_example">
        <div class="tab2_area"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

without el : $('.tab2_area') the view return :
    TypeError: element is null
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(elementToInsert, element.nextSibling);

i'm using xing-wysihtml5 on that view.

Comment: how many tabs do you see in total ? and how many with content in them ?

Comment: i have 3 tabs and all of this should have different content.

Comment: how many tabs do you actually see in the browser ? and which ones of them have content (visible in browser) ? If you see none, what are the errors you see in console ?

Comment: also, I don't see you attaching the `tabset` to the DOM something like `$("#body").html(this.tabset);`

Comment: i have a template for this.    
    <div class="tab_example">

Answer (score 0):

try

```
content : this.editorView.$el.html()
```